# SQL count number of records where value remains constant

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to find the count of `tracker_id` where `position` remains `1` through out the table.

```sql
tracker_id | position 
---------------------
 5         |     1
 11        |     1
 4         |     1
 4         |     2
 5         |     2
 4         |     1
 4         |     1
 11        |     1
 14        |     1
 9         |     2
```

Here, the output should be `2` since, `position` of `tracker_id`:`11` and `14` remains `1` through out the table.

Comment: Does the `position` have to be `1` or can it remain any value, as long as it's the same value?

Comment: @digital.aaron It has to be `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use not exists

```
select count(*) from tbl a
where not exists(select 1 
                 from tbl b 
                 where a.tracker_id = b.tracker_id 
                 and a.position  <> b.position )
and a.position = 1
```

Output: 2

Answer (score 2):

```sql
declare @table1 as table (tracker_id int,postion int)

insert into @table1 values (5,1)
insert into @table1 values (11,1)
insert into @table1 values (4,1)
insert into @table1 values (4,2)
insert into @table1 values (5,2)
insert into @table1 values (4,1)
insert into @table1 values (4,1)
insert into @table1 values (11,1)
insert into @table1 values (14,1)
insert into @table1 values (9,2)

select count(tracker_id),tracker_id,postion from @table1 group by tracker_id,postion
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `uncorrelated subquery`

```
select count(distinct tracker_id)
from t
where position=1
and tracker_id not in (select tracker_id from t where position<>1);
```

Using `window function`

```
select count(distinct tracker_id)
from (select *, avg(position) over (partition by tracker_id) as avg_pos from t) a
where avg_pos=1;
```

This one is just for giggles

```
select distinct count(*) over () 
from t
group by tracker_id 
having count(*) = sum(position);
```

And if you really want to have fun

```
select count(distinct tracker_id)-count(distinct case when position<>1 then tracker_id end)
from t;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```
select ( count(distinct tracker_id) - 
         count(distinct tracker_id) filter (where position <> 1)
       ) as num_all_1s
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

If `position` can only be `1`, then you can use this, which gets all the tracker_ids with only a single `position` value, and then limits that to those records where `position = 1`:

```
WITH agg AS
(
    SELECT 
        tracker_id 
        , p = MAX(position)
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY tracker_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT position) = 1
)
SELECT COUNT(tracker_id) 
FROM agg 
WHERE p = 1
```

Comment: Here, I can even change the `position` value. Nice solution. Thanks